CORS error on nodejs/express react app. CANT FIX NO MATTER WHAT IVE TRIED
so I'm getting a CORS error in my application.
This is the error below - followed my a net::ERR_FAILED 200(OK)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '???.herokuapp.com/api/apod' from origin '???.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My actual server.js file however should be fine and has the necessary CORS package installed and the correct options being used by the application before deployment.
     require('dotenv').config();
     const cors = require('cors');
     const express = require('express');
     const app = require('./app');
     const port = process.env.PORT || 10000;

     // CORS configuration
     const corsOptions = {
     origin: '*', // Allow all origins
     methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"], // Include all HTTP methods your API 
     uses
     allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"]
     };


     // Middleware
     app.use(cors(corsOptions));
     app.use(express.json()); 

     // Start server
     app.listen(port, () => {
       console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
     });


By the way, there's no point in asking me if I have the correct routes set up, if the env variables are set up perfectly or if I've made any mistakes on API calls between front and backend -> nope everything should be perfect and the application was running perfectly before DEPLOYMENT when it was being ran locally with a proxy to escape any CORS issue.
Now, this is honestly my first React/Node application as I usually develop with Angular/Java or Python and I've never had any CORS issues with those languages. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been...believe it or not...looking for a solution for upwards of two days now.
THANKS.

You require the app and then register the cors(...) middleware, which means that it comes after all other middlewares, when it is too late. (Same for the express.json() middleware.)

thanks for actually taking the time to reply but am I not already doing that?

The sequence of statements
const app = require('./app');
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

is equivalent to something like
/* The next three statements are contained in app.js. */
const app = express();
app.get("/api/apod", ...);
app.post("/api/apod", ...);
/* app.js ends with module.exports = app; */

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

This means that the middlewares for handling CORS and parsing JSON payloads are registered after the middlewares that handle the API requests. But they must be registered before them, otherwise they have no effect.
I suggest you move the two statements that register these middlewares also into app.js.
